# Display Sound waves for Audio recording

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch, audio-recording

How can we display sound waves as displayed in below image..

When user speaks, The yellow bars will animate based on user's volume.

[image]

I had gone through [apple demo](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/aurioTouch/Introduction/Intro.html) but didn't got anything.

Please guide me.. Is there any reference link available? Is there any sample tutorial available?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Check this sample project](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/avTouch/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008636-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) by APPLE. It contains same audio meter as your image.

May be that helps.

Comment: In case of any problem please leave comment.

Comment: We are colleagues in this community. Thax to StackOverflow. :D Cheers

Comment: Hmm... Thanks to StackOverflow... :D